# python 3 read array (list?) into new values

Tags: arrays, list, python-3.x

I have the following array, with (I think) sub lists within it:

```
items = [('this', 5, 'cm'), ('that', 3, 'mm'), ('other', 15, 'mm')]
```

I need to read it into new values for future calculations.
For example:

```
item1 = this
size1 = 5
unit1 = cm

item2 = that
size2 = 3
unit2 = mm
...
```

There may be more than 3 items in future arrays, so ideally some form of loop is needed?

Comment: Please check the updated answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19755361/2689986

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in Python can be of 2 types - `Lists` & `Tuples`.
`list` is mutable (i.e. you can change the elements as & when you wish)
`tuple` is immutable (read only array)

`list`  is represented by `[1, 2, 3, 4]`
`tuple` is represented by `(1, 2, 3, 4)`

Thus, the given array is a `list` of `tuples`!
You can nest tuples in lists but not lists in tuples.

This is more pythonic -

```
items = [('this', 5, 'cm'), ('that', 3, 'mm'), ('other', 15, 'mm')]

found_items = [list(item) for item in items]

for i in range(len(found_items)):
    print (found_items[i])

new_value = int(input ("Enter new value: "))

for i in range(len(found_items)):
    recalculated_item = new_value * found_items[i][1]
    print (recalculated_item)
```

**Output from above code** (taking input as 3)

```
['this', 5, 'cm']
['that', 3, 'mm']
['other', 15, 'mm']
15
9
45
```

**Update :** Following up on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755206/python-3-read-array-list-into-new-values#comment29358204_19755518) & [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19756697/2689986) I've updated the above code.

Comment: Perhaps I need a method of writing the original data in a different way? I can understand how you are printing things, but ultimately I need to assign the sizes to new integer values and calculate on them.
So, later I can have size x 2 and get 10 (and 6 and 30 on the other values for instance)

Comment: You can use the `item, size, unit` variables as you like. I used `print` to show how you could use them in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Following on Ashish Nitin Patil's answer...

If there are are going to be more than three items in the future you can use the asterisk to unpack the items in the tuples.

```
items = [('this', 5, 'cm'), ('that', 3, 'mm'), ('other', 15, 'mm')]
for x in items:
    print(*x)

#this 5 cm
#that 3 mm
#other 15 mm
```

Note: Python 2.7 doesn't seem to like the asterisk in the print method.

**Update:**
It looks like you need to use a second list of tuples that defines the property names of each value tuple:

```
props = [('item1', 'size2', 'unit1'), ('item2', 'size2', 'unit2'), ('item3', 'size3', 'unit3')]
values = [('this', 5, 'cm'), ('that', 3, 'mm'), ('other', 15, 'mm')]

for i in range(len(values)):
    value = values[i]
    prop = props[i]
    for j in range(len(item)):
        print(prop[j], '=', value[j])

# output
item1 = this
size2 = 5
unit1 = cm
item2 = that
size2 = 3
unit2 = mm
item3 = other
size3 = 15
unit3 = mm
```

The caveat here is that you need to make sure that the elements in the props list are matched sequentially with the elements in the values list.

Comment: Intended output is that:
1.program reads array of items from text file.
2. prompts user for new value
3. the sizes from array items are recalculated
I think I need to index the array items and then assign to new values to perform calculations on?

Comment: I now need something like this at the end:

newvalue = int(input ("Enter new value:"))
newsize2 = size2 * newvalue
print (newsize2)

Comment: I've Updated my answer accordingly. Please check.

Comment: Yes, this is fine for printing the data out, but I need to perform calculations on it as per my comment above.  I there need to write the array parts to new variables (I think?)